# More on convergence of $\prod (1+a_n)$ where $a_n$ changes sign

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

I have seen that infinite products $\prod(1+a_n)$ where $a_n$ can change sign repeatedly is more complicated than in situations where $-1 < a_n <0$ or $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ where product and series $\sum a_n$ must both converge or diverge. From other questions I understand that if $\sum a_n^2$ converges then simultaneous convergence/divergence of $\prod (1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ still holds.  I also was given the example $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $\sum a_n$ converges and $\prod(1+a_n)$ diverges.  In this case we also have $\sum a_n^2 = \sum\frac{1}{n}$ divergent.

Summarizing,  I know that 
$$\sum a_n^2 \text{  converges}, \quad \prod(1+a_n) \text{   converges} \implies \sum a_n \text{   converges}$$
and I have an example where
$$\prod(1+a_n) \text{ diverges}, \sum a_n \text{  converges, and } \sum a_n^2 \text{  diverges}$$

My question is if $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges (where $a_n$ changes sign) must both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum a_n^2$ converge?

Comment: Should we assume if the product converges, then it converges to a nonzero value?

Comment: @zhw: Yes -- I believe the convention for products is convergence to $0$ is considered "divergence".

Comment: Well that convention is not universal. So I usually ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $a_n = e^{(-1)^n/\sqrt n}-1.$ Then $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges. But

$$\sum a_n = \sum \left (e^{(-1)^n/\sqrt n} -1\right) = \sum \left (\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n} + \frac{1}{2n} + O(1/n^{3/2})\right ).$$

The series on the right is the sum of a convergent series, a divergent series, and a convergent series. Hence it diverges.